# Run program installed on desktop in wine

Tags: ubuntu, wine

I am trying to get Warcraft II Battle Edition (http://en.war2.ru/) to work on Ubuntu (14.04) by running it through wine. I was able to successfully get through the installation menu of Warcraft in wine, but I have no idea how to launch the program after installation. It said it created a desktop application, where it would obviously be easy to run if I were on windows. But since I am running this through wine, how would I launch the program

There was a file War2Combat.desktop created on my desktop in Ubuntu, but when I run it as ./War2Combat.desktop a popup menu appears saying "War2 not found. please copy this program to war2 directory and start again.

I do not know where this directory is.

So once again, how to I get this program to run through wine?

Answer (score 0):

Find the game under your WINEPREFIX (probably ~/.wine) and then launch it either by double-clicking the .exe or launching a terminal and typing:

`wine .wine/drive_c/path/to/game/WarCraft.exe (or whatever the file is called)`

Answer (score 0):

If your intent is to run a program that is already installed outside of Wine's C partition:
then simply run `winecfg`
in appeared window choose the drives tab
and add the partition containing the program to the list in front of you
then it can be opened with Wine either by "open with wine" or by executing `wine drive_letter/path_to_program` where drive_letter is the same letter chosen for the partition in winecfg

Answer (score -1):

I'm Assuming that its not installed via wine, you should be able to navigate to the warcraft directory and run the EXE from there and if it does run i think you can create a shortcut with the command

```
wine [Programdir1]\[Programdir2]\program.exe
```

I would recommend installing POL though it makes this kinda thing a breeze.